# Export google search to a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-search, scrape

Is it possible for me to create a list of google search results from a specific query and export it into excel?  For example, I'd like to google orthodontists in Florida and be able to export the business name, phone number and address to an excel spreadsheet.  I've done a lot of searching but I can't find any solutions.  I'm looking for someone to point me in the right direction.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [API is an Application Programming Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) and it's a way for your software to interact with the software on a server. Google has an API called the "[Custom Search Engine](https://www.google.com/cse/all)" which you can use for 100 free queries per day. Other search engines may have more generous free APIs. With a search API you can write a code to download text that contain all the relevant data. You can read more about search engine APIs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8157344/2327328).

Another way to collect data from google is to scrape their page. This means that you use a code to download the HTML, and from that HTML you collect the relevant pieces ([wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)). With a programming language like python, many people use the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library for scraping. With code then you can take the relevant parts of the HTML and put it into a format like CSV that is readable by Excel. With python there are ways to write to Excel, directly, too ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13437727/2327328)).

Finally, [here is a link](http://googlesystem.blogspot.ch/2007/09/google-spreadsheets-lets-you-import.html) from 2007 that says with Google Spreadsheets you can import HTML.

**Update:** [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/get-external-data-from-a-web-page-HA010218472.aspx) is the MS Excel version.

Comment: The Custom Search Engine is limited to one or more sites that you specify, and one is not allowed to use a url pattern that would search the whole web.

Answer (score 0):

The following web app https://www.resultstoexcel.com/ allows you to download Google search results to a CSV file, a Microsoft Excel readable format, for free.
If you have any problem viewing the downloaded results correctly in MS Excel, please read the FAQs section where you will find how to open the file using the correct column separators.

Where are the results coming from?
A Google search on the topic retrieves many companies that offer online access to Google Search Results through an Application Programming Interface (API). This web app uses SERPSBOT API.